# Tomcat connection pooling reset by sql server 2008 and 2012

Tags: sql-server, connection-pooling

I have 5 different modules connecting sql server 2008 and 2012 using Tomcat connection pooling.

In the Tomcat7\conf\context.xml

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" logAbandoned="true" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/testservice2" password="abc" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=testdb;SelectMethod=Cursor" username="abc"/>
```

Module 1 - In the Tomcat7\conf\localhost\Module1.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/Module1">
    <Resource name="jdbc/testdb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
               username="abc" password="abc" driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=testdb;SelectMethod=Cursor"/>
```

Module 2 - In the Tomcat7\conf\localhost\Module2.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/Module2">
    <Resource name="jdbc/testdb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
               username="abc" password="abc" driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=testdb;SelectMethod=Cursor"/>
</Context>
```

Module 3 - In the Tomcat7\conf\localhost\Module3.XML

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/Module3">
    <Resource name="jdbc/testdb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
               username="abc" password="abc" driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=testdb;SelectMethod=Cursor"/>
</Context>
```

Module 4 - In the Tomcat7\conf\localhost\Module4.XML

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/Module4">
    <Resource name="jdbc/testdb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
               username="abc" password="abc" driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=testdb;SelectMethod=Cursor"/>
</Context>
```

I'm experiencing the below error on QA server as well as staging server?
06-Apr-2015 07:43:28 ERROR DBAccess:49 - I/O Error: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

What's wrong with my Tomcat 7 connection pool configuration? why it's rejected by sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use all the modules simultaneously in which you have defined the 'Resource' with same name i.e. name="jdbc/testdb" as far as i know this name has to be unique because it is jndi bound with the value you give to name attribute(see tomcat document https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Resource_Definitions ). If you define a datasource with same name in different modules(web apps) see that they are not in use simultaneously. Somewhere in your server this is happening. To be safe use different name for 'Resource'.
Another thing-Is 'Resource' with name="jdbc/testservice2" being used in any of your five modules you have mentioned. Cause I don't see a connection between any of your five modules with this 'Resource'.